# Does HTMLUnit include a functional [HTML5] canvas 2D implementation able to render image data back to Java Code?

Tags: java, javascript, html, canvas, htmlunit

Basically, I'd like to be able to retrieve the HTMl[5] canvas image data created from, normal, JavaScript-based in-browser scripting. I'd like to do this in the context of a screen-scraping-type environment, from within [pure] Java code. [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) appears to fit some of the requirements.

How would I go about retrieving the canvas-rendered image data, and how complete, or not, might HTMLUnit's canvas implementation currently be (version 2.13 at time of writing)?

Two (2) HTMlUnit classes of note, *might* be:

com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlCanvas
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.canvas.CanvasRenderingContext2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well [answering my own question], as far as can see, no, there is not a functioning HTML Canvas implementation, as of HTMLUnit version 2.13 (November 2013).

Interestingly, it might be useful to integrate the following HTML Canvas (2D) open-source solution into HTMLUnit, in order to render canvas-based graphics:

https://github.com/w3canvas/javacanvas

It should also be possible to create a WebGL canvas context by appropriating the WebGL interface/class code from something like the [gwtGL](https://code.google.com/p/gwtgl/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FGwtGL%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgooglecode%2Fgwtgl%2Fbinding) project, and implementing a 3D layer atop of an existing OpenGL 2.0 Java library.

Can I haz some points now?