# Convert html canvas into bitmap java jsoup

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, jsoup

Alright, I'm trying to use jsoup to download an image, but that image is a canvas. I have not found any way to convert an html canvas using jsoup into a bitmap image that I can display in an imageview.

My code so far

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://wvde.state.wv.us/closings/at-a-glance").get();
            Elements img = document
                    .select("canvas#myCanvas");
```

but I can't find out how to convert the canvas into a bitmap. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can't do this using only jsoup; that image is drawn in javascript

Comment: @user1121883 is there a way I can do this? It doesn't matter if it uses other stuff.

Comment: not sure it can: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696932/does-htmlunit-include-a-functional-html5-canvas-2d-implementation-able-to-rend