# Convert coordinates from event.offsetX and event.offsetY into webGL native coordinates

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I have this webGL program written in JavaScript where I have to draw a point on a canvas on a spot where the user clicks. To do this, I need to get the coordinates of the spot where the user clicked. I accomplish this by using JavaScript's `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` to get coordinates of a spot relative to the top left of my canvas. The thing here is that webGL uses a different coordinate system where the coordinates are relative to the center of the canvas. Any ideas on how I can convert my `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` coordinates into webGL's coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

WebGL, like any other 3d graphics environments, operates in a different coordinate system from what canvas deals with. Instead of pixels, X/Y/Z have value from -1.0 to 1.0. If you are trying to convert from the screen coordinate (pixels) to normalized device coordinates (NDC), the process is fairly straight forwards (see below), however if you are trying to convert into your scene's coordinate system then it is highly dependant on the way you are projecting the scene onto the screen.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328472/how-webgl-works), read the section titled **Normalized Device Coordinates** for more information and examples on converting between Screen Coordinates and NDCs.